# Number formatting in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a number that needs to be formatted like this:

- Thousands need to be separated with `.`
- Decimals need to be separated with `,`

For example, number `1,234,567.89` needs to look like `1.234.567,89`.

Is there any way that I can do this with a simple sql function or I have to make my own function?

Comment: You mention `PL/SQL` as a tag. Are you on Oracle DBMS?

Comment: What's the data type of the `1,234,567.89`? Is it stored or passed in as  `VARCHAR2`? and RDBMS is Oracle right?

Comment: Data type in database is number, and it looks like 1234567.89
Yes, I am working in Oracle DBMS

Comment: That's not really a SQL issue. Format in layer above.

Comment: Either change the value of `nls_numeric_characters=,.` system/session wide or use `to_char(number_col, 'fm999G999G990D099', 'nls_numeric_characters=,.')` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `to_char()` together with the specification that you want to use `,` as the decimal separator and `.` for the thousands separator (which is not the default in Oracle)

```
select to_char(1234567.89, '9G999G999G999D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
from dual;
```

Results in: `1.234.567,89`

Details about format models: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211

Details about the to_char() function: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions201.htm#SQLRF51882

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively also work with the session territory setting.

```
create table mytest (field1 number);
insert into mytest values (1234567.89);
alter session set NLS_TERRITORY=GERMANY;
select field1, to_char(field1,'9G999G999G999D00') from mytest;
alter session set NLS_TERRITORY=AMERICA;
select field1, to_char(field1,'9G999G999G999D00') from mytest;
```

Output:

```
Table created.
1 row created.
Session altered.

    FIELD1 TO_CHAR(FIELD1,'9G999G999G999D00')
---------- ----------------------------------
1234567,89      1.234.567,89                 
1 row selected.
Session altered.

    FIELD1 TO_CHAR(FIELD1,'9G999G999G999D00')
---------- ----------------------------------
1234567.89      1,234,567.89                 
1 row selected.
```